# Regex rookie needs assistance

Tags: php, regex

I'm totally useless at regex, any advice much appreciated.

```
$url = 'http://somedomain.com?var=<##var##>&var2=<##var2##>';
echo preg_replace('^<##(.*)##>$', '', $url);
```

Trying to strip anything between (and including) <## and ##>. So my result would be:

```
http://somedomain.com?var=&var2=
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/ you can use this site to test your regex against data.  It helps a lot.

Comment: are the #s actually there or are they representing something else?

Comment: they represent nothing, just need to be stripped (along with the contained value).

Comment: The ^ and $ mark the start and end of line. I don't think they belong in your regexp since you are trying to match parts of url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code should be:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://somedomain.com?var=<##var##>&var2=<##var2##>';
$newUrl = preg_replace('/<##.*?##>/', '', $url);
echo $url;
?>
```

The `^` and `$` you used are wrong, they represend the begin or the end of the string and you won't replace only the `<##...##>` part if `<##` is at the beginning and `##>` at the end of the string.

Also the `?` after `.*` means that it matches everything from the `<##` until the next `##>`. If you use `.*` it matches everything from the first `<##` until the last `##>` so you result would be `http://somedomain.com?var=`

Answer (score 2):

Replace all matches of `<##.*?##>` with an empty string.

```
$url = 'http://somedomain.com?var=<##var##>&var2=<##var2##>';
echo preg_replace('/<##.*?##>/', '', $url);
```

The trick is the the ?, which means 'Match as little as possible, but as much as I have to.'

Comment: but your first PHP code won't work. You forgot the required `//` or `##` tokens before and after a regex: `'/<##.*?##>/'`

Answer (score 1):

You're close with your regex.

`^` means "start of line", and `$`, means "end of line".  Remove them, otherwise it'll only match if the whole string is `<##var##>`.

`.*` means match anything.  Including `>`.  Your regex will match `<##var##>&var2=<##var2##>` and not just each group.

Try this regex:

```
<##([^>]*)##>
```

Comment: @WouterJ: I'm not too good with regex, how would I do that?  Is that the `.*?` trick you did?

Comment: Yes it is. `.*` is a greedy match and `.*?` is an ungreedy match

Comment: @WouterJ: Cool, didn't know that.  Thanks.  I'll leave this answer here as an alternative solution :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('(<##.+?##>)', '', $url);
```